# How can you access the log of attempts to access a storage location in Google Cloud done from a mobile device with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

The person who is using Firebase on a mobile device to upload files to Google Storage should have access to a log that reports each access attempt, the remote IP address, and the outcome of the access attempt.  I do not see this from my Firebase console.  This is a concern, since as someone with a bucket in the Google Cloud storage, I would like to see each attempt from a mobile device logged.  Right now it would help with debugging problems on the mobile device, but when a system goes into production, doesn't the owner of the bucket want to see each access attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you would need to use Audit logs, you need to activate them though, you can do this through you console with the menu at the top left, then you would need to access to IAM & Admin > audit logs, here you would need to find cloud storage, and change the configuration in order start logging this actions (I believe these logs cover all that you described), you can follow the link on [3] if you need more information about how to activate them.

In order to view the logs, you would need to go to logging > logs viewer, here you need to select your service (cloud storage) and then you can select the type of logs (audited logs).

Here are some useful links that you could use if you need more information.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration

[3] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access?hl=uk#config-console